# App also terminates when "end" button is pressed for coming back from GPS settings

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want some directions here. I have 3-Activities in an app i.e. MainActivity, MapViewActivity and DbActivity. I goes from one activity to another via. intents. The code of each intent is:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityName.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I have used

> android:noHistory="true"

in all these activities, so that when the mobile "end" button is pressed the app gets stop. Otherwise app was going back..... in spite of stoping the app
Now the problem is: **When app goes for the GPS settings after finding GPS service off, the user turns on GPS and presses the mobile "end" button to come back to the app. But app also get stop.** So user again start the app and comes on MapViewActivity. If I remove android:noHistory="true" from MapViewActivity, the problem also comes back. So is there any other solution for. Please guide me, if there is some method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you mean "end". You probably mean "back". If you don't want the user to return to the activity when the user clicks "back", then just call `finish()` after you start the next activity. Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
// finish this activity so that the user doesn't come back to it
finish();
```

Please take out the `android:noHistory="true"` from the manifest, this probably isn't what you want.